# How to get statistics about uri in azure

Tags: azure, statistics, storage, cdn

I would like to know how to get statistics about URI in Azure.

We are currently providing services using CDN + Storage. Here, each file stored in storage has a different endpoint, and in this case, I would like to calculate statistics for each endpoint.

I checked the related method in AWS, but there was no way to find out in Azure, so I decided to post this.

Talented people, please help!

---

I was able to check overall data statistics in the Azure CDN management section, but I could not check detailed URI statistics.

We are trying additional monitoring settings to see if it is possible, but we were also unable to check the data after setting it up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To get statistics about URI in Azure, you can use the real-time stats feature in Azure CDN Premium from Edgio. This feature provides real-time data, such as bandwidth, cache statuses, and concurrent connections to your CDN profile when delivering content to your clients.

`Note that the real-time statistics feature is available with Azure CDN Premium from Edgio (formerly known as Verizon). If you're using a different CDN tier or provider in Azure (like Standard from Microsoft or Standard from Akamai), the availability of real-time stats may differ.`

You can access the real-time stats by following these steps:

1. In the Azure Portal, browse to your CDN profile.

[image]

2. From the CDN profile blade, click the Manage button.

[image]

3. Hover over the Analytics tab, then hover over the Real-Time Stats flyout. Click on HTTP Large Object.

[image]

The real-time stats graphs are displayed, and each of the graphs displays real-time statistics for the selected time span, starting when the page loads. The graphs update automatically every few seconds. The Bandwidth graph displays the amount of bandwidth used for the current platform over the selected time span. The shaded portion of the graph indicates bandwidth usage. The exact amount of bandwidth currently being used is displayed directly below the line graph.

Unfortunately, there is no way to get detailed URI statistics in Azure. However, you can enable raw logs and select to stream logs to Azure Storage, Event hubs, or Azure Log Analytics. With Azure Log Analytics, you can view monitoring metrics and set up alerts. For more information, see Azure CDN HTTP raw logs.

References:

- [Real-time stats in Microsoft Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-real-time-stats#real-time-stats-in-microsoft-azure-cdn)
- [Raw logs for Azure CDN from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/monitoring-and-access-log#metrics)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply.

As you mentioned, it was difficult to find detailed information about URI.

However, if you click [Analysis > Report > Top Referring Pages] in CDN, you can check statistical information about the endpoint as shown below. Some accounts will see this feature, others won't. How do I know how to use this feature in the same way?

Comment: Depends on the CDN profile type. For example in case of the "Top Referring Pages" feature, if it's not available in your current Azure CDN product or account, you might need to consider if switching to a different CDN product or upgrading to [premium](https://i.imgur.com/2DKzAh2.png) pricing tier